# Such As Relate To

Tags: comparative-constructions

Could it be that this:

"firearm laws ***as they relate to*** public schools"

is a variation of:

"firearms laws ***such as relate to*** public schools"

?

Comment: No. **As they relate to** can't be rewritten as **such as relate to** here. You can rewrite your first sentence as **Firearm laws as far as it concerns to public schools** or simply **Firearm laws concerning public schools**.

Answer (score 1):

*As* here limits the scope of the discussion: the author says she is talking about **all** firearms laws but only to the extent that they are related to public schools, not about any other aspect of those laws.

*Firearms laws **such as relate to** public schools* means something slightly different. This is equivalent to *such laws as relate to*, and restricts the discussion to a subset of the laws: only those which relate to public schools.

There is considerable ambiguity in the notion of *relate to*: any given firearms law may be understood to "relate to" public schools either by virtue of specific provisions in the law or by virtue of some ancillary impact. Because the *such as relate to* construction defines a subset, it implies the narrower reading: those firearms laws which have specific provisions relating to public schools. The *as they relate to* does not define a subset but refers to a specific aspect of the superset; it therefore implies the broader reading, all firearms laws insofar as they have some impact on public schools.

In some circumstances, the the two expressions may in some contexts be practically equivalent. For instance, if all firearms laws have provisions specifically relating to public schools, the subset of *laws such as relate to public schools* is identical with the superset.

But if this is not the case, if only **some** firearms laws have such provisions, the author may still hold that **all** firearms laws have ancillary impact on public schools: the expression *as they relate to* leaves it open for her to discuss the superset.

Comment: So, what does "such as relate to" mean compared to "as they (laws) relate to"?

Comment: @meatie See my rewrite

Comment: In some corners of this site, it is suggested that "as they (laws) relate to" means "in the way they relate to", not "to the extent that they relate to".  Could this alternative definition be wrong?

Comment: @meatie **All** the terms we're throwing around here are pretty vague, but *the way that* or *how* are way up the vagueness ladder from even *relate to*. An *in the way that they relate to* clause is basically a pro-adverb - you can replace it with just about any adverb you like. It has structural rather than semantic meaning.

Comment: I have a feeling that "firearm laws ***as they relate to*** public schools" is not a standalone noun phrase, because the "***as they relate to...***" part seems to describe some action being done to the laws, and does not describe an intrinsic property of the laws.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @meatie In this comment, and in your earlier questions about *as*, you seem to be fixed on 'activity' or 'action' as a semantic category. But verbs do not only express 'actions', they also express 'states': *be*, *exist*, *know*, *relate to*. And in any case, the subject of *relate to* here is the laws themselves, not something which 'does something' to them.

Comment: How about "as they affect" and "as they concern" as in "firearm laws ***as they affect*** public schools" and "firearm laws ***as they concern*** public schools"?  Aren't "affect" and "concern" activity/action verbs?

Comment: @meatie Sure. They are actions whose Agents are the firearms laws.

Comment: Would "***with the way*** they(laws) relate to" be a good substitute for "as they(laws) relate to"?

Comment: @meatie mmm Perhaps *with respect to the way they relate to*

Comment: Would "firearm laws ***relating to public schools in the way they (firearm laws) do***" be equivalent to "firearm laws ***as they relate to*** public schools"?

Comment: @meatie No. That's just a [**tautology**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rhetoric)): *FL which relate to PS in the way FL relate to PS.*

Comment: How about "firearm laws ***relating to public schools in this way***"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15486/discussion-between-stoneyb-and-meatie).